# Azure AD B2C library for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c

What is the recommended/famous library for authenticating the react app with **Azure AD B2C**?

I am familiar with [Salvoravida React Adal](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal) which has approximately 8500+ downloads per week in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal). Is there anything similar for AD B2C.

Based on my search, I found [react-azure-adb2c](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c), but it looks like it's not maintained anymore (last commit on Aug 2018 & a lot of pending PRs )

Comment: msal.js is probably the closest - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you worry about something about react-azure-adb2c, you can use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to integrate Azure AD B2C with your application. Microsoft also recommends customers use MSAL.js to integrate Azure AD B2C. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview). Regarding how to do that, you can refer to [react-msal-sample](https://github.com/sunilbandla/react-msal-sample) and [MSAL Azure AD B2C sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).